# API Google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Como faço para fazer um mapa personalizado, estilo esse:

http://noroestecom.com.br/a-empresa

usando a API do google, não sei por onde começar.

Answer (score 1):

Igor, uma boa pesquisa na parte de [Developers no google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=pt-br) pode te ajudar bastante, eles tem vários exemplos e uma documentação muito boa, para o seu propósito tem esse exemplo [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=pt-br)

Segue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lembrando que é importante ter a [sua própria API KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=pt-br)